# HTML returning empty NDB Key to Python

Tags: python, html, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm returning the key to an ndb entity like this:

```
<form action="/vote?article_key = {{ a.key.urlsafe() }}" method="post">
                <td><input name= "vote" type="submit" value="Up!"></td>
                <td><input name= "vote" type="submit" value="Down!"></td>
</form>
```

And then trying to retrieve the right ndb Article entity via the key this way:

```
def post(self):
    article_key = self.request.get('article_key')
    article = ndb.Key(article_key).get()
```

But it seems like i'm always getting an empty string from the HTML.
Moreover, is that the right way to retrieve an entity given its key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the `article_key` parameter you get from the form from its "urlsafe" representation to an actual NDB Key:

```
article = ndb.Key(urlsafe=article_key).get()
```